# How to handle subcategories for checkboxes - Mobile App?

Tags: mobile-application, checkboxes

So I've got a list of items that user's can subscribe to. Selecting which items you want will be easy; a simple check box will suffice. However, what is a good way to go about displaying the subcategories? Ideally, I would like users to be able to choose to subscribe to all the sports, all the men's sports, or all the women's sports in one click as well as be able to choose individually which ones to subscribe to. Here is the setup of the categories:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try by incorporating checkboxes to accordion something like this
where by default all the headers in accordion are hidden and an user can select all of them by a single click but if he wants to select specific fields in them he clicks the header where they drill down as shown and he can select the required items

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, I'd also add a slight visual cue like a **line under the main category** or a slight underlying **background color**, so it's easier for the user to tell apart sub and main categories